# Devise authentication and linking social accounts with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have an app set up to use Devise for authentication. I am wanting users to be able to link their social media accounts to my app after they have logged in via my devise setup.

I am not looking to let them sign in via social accounts. OmniAuth is what I've been looking into but I'm getting quite confused. All the guides I see are for the initial logging into the app via 3rd party accounts.

Any advice?

**Clarification:**
I want to store their credentials for social apps (Twitter, Facebook, etc) within my app - to allow me to make posts on their behalf. The logging in should still be done via Devise.

Comment: What do you mean by "link" their social accounts?

Comment: Sorry when I say link I mean my rails app has access to their social accounts to make posts on their behalf

Comment: Add the clarifications to the question, not in comments.  That means you need to store their credentials or more likely access tokens. This is more of a  3rd party API issue because I imagine each social media account has different mechanisms.

Comment: Done this. I will search further as I think the way you phrased it will help me find what I'm looking for.